# Split string into array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have a string with the following structure.

string = "[abcd, abc, a, b, abc]"

I would like to convert that into an array. I keep using the split function in Python but I get spaces and the brackets on the start and the end of my new array. I tried working around it with some if statements but I keep missing letters in the end from some words.

Keep in mind that I don't know the length of the elements in the string. It could be 1, 2, 3 etc.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code please.

Comment: " I tried working around it " what did you try and what was the specific problem you ran into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove `[` and `]` from your string, then split on commas, then remove spaces from resulting items (using `strip`).

Comment: Or just split on comma+space.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your elements never end or start with spaces or square brackets, you could just strip them out (the bracket can be stripped out before splitting):

```
arr = [ x.strip() for x in string.strip('[]').split(',') ]
```

It gives as expected

```
print (arr)
['abcd', 'abc', 'a', 'b', 'abc']
```

The nice part with `strip` is that it leaves all inner characters untouched. With:

```
string = "[ab cd, a[b]c, a, b, abc]"
```

You get: `['ab cd', 'a[b]c', 'a', 'b', 'abc']`

Comment: for bigger lists removing the brackets first and then splitting would be more efficient.

Comment: and the `.strip()` could be avoided if you would do `.split(', ')` (split on comma + space)

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this

```
>>> s = string[1:len(string)-1].split(", ")
>>> s
['abcd', 'abc', 'a', 'b', 'abc']
```

Answer (score 1):

If the values in this list are variables themselves (looks like it because they're not quoted) the easiest way to convert this string to the equivalent list is

```
string = eval(string)
```

Caution: If the values in your list should be strings this will not work.

Answer (score 1):

another way to solve this problem

```
string = "[abcd, abc, a, b, abc]"
result = string[1:len(string)-1].split(", ")
print(result)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use `strip`, it can be done by following rather clumsy way:

```
arr = [e[1:] for e in string.split(',')]
arr[len(arr)-1]=arr[len(arr)-1].replace(']', '')


print(arr)
['abcd', 'abc', 'a', 'b', 'abc']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following.

```
[list_element.strip() for list_element in string.strip("[]").split(",")]
```

First remove brackets and then split it accordingly.